# Can I use a range of values in a single switch?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm trying to simplify a Card class, and am wondering if there's any way to use a range of values in a switch statement?

CONSIDER:

```
 if((card<14))
     suit="Hearts";
     else
     if((card>14)&&(card<27))
         suit="Clubs";

             etc.
```

Instead I'd like to use a switch statement, such as:

```
switch(card){
    case1: through case13:
    suit="Hearts";
    break;

       etc.
```

I wasn't able to find anything in the Java Tutorials that suggest there is such a variation of switch. But is there?

Comment: For this particular case, you could do a `switch` on `(card-1) / 13`, or something like that.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: If I read this right, `int foo = (card-1) / 13;` will yield integer values 1-4, which can then be passed to the `switch`. Am I understanding that properly?

Comment: Yes.  Or something like that, depending on how you've numbered the cards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java,Using switch statement with a range of value in each case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873590/in-java-using-switch-statement-with-a-range-of-value-in-each-case)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

About the best you can do is something like this (see below). So in some cases (no pun intended :)), it's just better to use an if statement.

```
switch(card){
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 10:
    case 11:
    case 12:
    case 13:
        suit="Hearts";
        break;
}
```

However, another approach you could consider is using a map.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 14; ++i) {
  map.put(i, "Hearts");
}
for (int i = 15; i <= 26; ++i) {
  map.put(i, "Clubs");
}
```

Then you can look up the card's suit using the map.

```
String suit1 = map.get(12); // suit1 will be Hearts after the assignment
String suit2 = map.get(23); // suit2 will be Clubs after the assignment
```

Comment: Map...another interesting feature beyond my newbie-ness...I've got a weekend reseach project or two. :)   Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Java doesn't allow you to do any such thing unfortunately. Other JVM languages might though, i.e., [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/).

Comment: Darn. OK...thanks. I was hoping I was just suffering from newbie-blindness. :)

Answer (score 1):

This was proposed in Project Coin some time back.

Basically the switch operator now operates on built-ins and Objects.  While a well defined range exists for selecting two built-ins, switches that are operating on Objects don't have a well defined range.  Currently two classes of objects are supported, `Strings` and `Enum`.

Is "car" between "A" and "D"?  Depends on how you like to handle case sensitivity.

Is `MyEnum.ONE` before `MyEnum.TWO`?  Depending on it in production code is a very bad idea (as Josh Bloch would love to explain), and if you need an ordering, the maintainable way is to implement a non-index bound comparator.  This much better practice would be hard to integrate into a simple switch without forcing every enum to implement an ordering (which doesn't make sense for enums that are not ordered).

[The project coin proposal is found here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000213.html).

Josh Bloch's excellent presentation on why not to rely on implicit enum ordering [is found within the presentation here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1vQf4qyMXg).

Answer (score 0):

This is about the best you're going to get:

```
switch(card){
    case1:
    case2:
    case3:
        suit="Hearts";
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some libraries provide the "Range" feature. It will not work with the switch syntax but it should do the job.

For example, the [Range](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html) class of [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

```
Range hearts = Ranges.closed(1, 13);
Range clubs = Ranges.closed(14, 17);
// ...

if (hearts.contains(value)) {
    // case heart...
} else if (clubs.contains(value) {
    // case club...
} // ...
```