# efficient way to calculate Range without using if else

Tags: java, integer, range, if-statement

cash range ------------> tax

5,000 - 30,000--------> 700

30,001- 60,000-------- > 1,000

60,001 - 125,000 -------> 1,600

125,001 - 250,000 ---------> 3,000

250,001 - 500,000 -------- > 5,000

500,001 - 1,000,000---------> 9,000

How I can implement this in a efficient way? What if I don't want to use IF/Else for that.

Comment: If you are using Java 6 or above use java.util.NavigableMap

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java,Using switch statement with a range of value in each case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873590/in-java-using-switch-statement-with-a-range-of-value-in-each-case)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an excellent case for a `NavigableMap` implementation. You can use its `ceilKey` method to directly get what you need. Your keys will be the upper bounds of the ranges and the values will be the tax amounts.

Comment: Are you able to provide a similar fashioned example for C#, I'm curious what would be a proper implementation for the same case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Great, Hoping for other suggestions otherwise will accept this nice alternative.

Comment: @Peter Sorry, I'm not a C# user.

Comment: Thank you anyway. I'll try to research.