# How to use switch in array comparison?

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement

I want to compare array length with some `int` values. I can do it with `if` `else` but how to do it with `switch` because `switch` is fast and I want to use that in my project

```
switch (array.length) {
    case array.length <= 11: // how to do this 
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

With `if else` I can do this:

```
if (array.length <= 5) { 
    //my is code here 
}
else if (array.length <= 15) {
    //my is code here 
}
else if (array.length <= 10) {
    //my is code here 
}
```

Comment: I this [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873590/in-java-using-switch-statement-with-a-range-of-value-in-each-case/19062152#19062152) answer is clever

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. `switch` can only test exact values.

You could do:

```
switch(array.length) {
case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3:
case 4: case 5: case 6: case 7:
case 8: case 9: case 10: case 11:
    // do stuff
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

But *why* do you want to do this? What makes you think it's faster?

Answer (score 0):

`switch` is not the same as `if (...) { ... } else { ... }`. You can only use `==` within a `case`. You would have to do something like this:

```
int length = array.length;
switch (length) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
    [...]
    case 11:
        // your code here
        break;
    //other cases here
}
```

Notice the missing `break`-statements, they are quite important.
I would recommend [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it(as per your example) using `switch`. Since the values of `case` are constant expression (`case *value*`).

Answer (score 0):

`Switch` statements operate by exact matches rather than comparisons like `if` does. You can do what you want by introducing a new variable like this:

```
int value = (array.length <= 11 ? 0 : (array.length <= 20 ? 1 : 2));
switch (value) {
    case 0:  // 11 or under
    break;
    case 1:  // 12 to 20
    break;
    case 2:  // 21 or more
    break;
}
```

I don't know if this buys you much over `if`/`else` statements, but if you find it cleaner to code, you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

In your if/elseif, the `if(array.length<=10)` will never run because if`(array.length<=15)` is checked above it.

Doing this with an if/elseif structure would require less lines of code.
If you want to do this using a switch/case statement, this would work:

```
int length = array.length;

    switch(length) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5: {
        System.out.println("Case 0<=length<=5 triggered.");
        break;
    }
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 10: {
        System.out.println("Case 6<=length<=10 triggered.");
        break;
    }
    case 11:
    case 12:
    case 13:
    case 14:
    case 15: {
        System.out.println("Case 10<=length<=15 triggered.");
        break;
    }
    default: {
        System.out.println("Default case triggered.");
    }
    }
```