# coldfusion cfscript, switch/case where case between a range

Tags: coldfusion, switch-statement

I've got a problem where I want to do one of three things...
if the value of x is 1-5 (inclusive) do A, if x is between 6-13 (inclusive) do B, and if x is between 14-16 do C.

I figured the switch case would be ok, although I guess I could use a plain IF / ELSE IF, however, as I coded it, I can't help but think there is a more elegant way of stating this USING the switch/case (just in case I encounter a similar need that has more then three options).

here is what I have:

```
switch ( x ) {
    case 1:case 2:case 3:case 4:case 5:
        // DO A
        break;
    case 6:case 7:case 8:case 9:case 10:case 11:case 12:case 13:
        // DO B
        break;
    case 14:case 15:case 16:
        // DO C
        break;
}
```

is there a way in the case to specify "between" (inclusive or exclusive)?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope.  Switch statement are designed to work with single, [*constant* values](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a0e0-7fdf.html#WSB69283B9-CA98-4fdf-95C2-80665F57BC82). Unless [the comparison is such that the value can be modified to conform to that rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19062152/104223), the only options are what you have written already OR using `if/else if/else`, AFAIK. In most cases, the latter is cleaner than a bunch of hard coded `case` statements IMO.

Comment: Ya, as I figured, after thinking about it - with 3 options, it'd be cleaner to do 
IF ( x >= 1 && x <=5 )... in THIS instance... I just needed to know for future reference. thx

Comment: Yep.  My approach is go with whichever one makes the intent of the expression more clear. For ranges, and other complex comparisons, that usually means `if/elseif`.