# Switch statement to determine letter grade from user input (decimal)

Tags: java

My instructor wants me to use a switch statement, but I'm calculating the grade of a student and by nature I would think to use double but I can't. The program should ask for user input then by which ever number (example: 92.99) the student enters, print out a letter grade according to the syllabus. Please help!
In addition that doesn't work correctly anymore. It doesn't print out the letter grade.
This is what I have so far:

```
public class calculate {

    private static String gradefinal;
    private static char grade;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // variable declaration

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    //Input device scanner
        double finalgrade = 0.0; 

    // input 

        String first_name;              //Holds first name 
        System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
        first_name = in.next();

        String last_name;               //Holds last name 
        System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
        last_name = in.next();

        String major;                   //Holds user's major
        System.out.print("Enter your intended major: ");
        major = in.next();

        String ist;                     //Holds user's class number
        System.out.print("Enter the IST class you are in: ");
        ist = in.next();

        String final_grade;         //Holds user's letter grade
        System.out.print("Enter your final grade: ");
        final_grade = in.next();

        // process 



        if (finalgrade <= 59.99) 
        {
            grade = 'F';

        }
        else if (finalgrade >= 90.00)
        {
            grade = 'A';
        }
        else if ((finalgrade <= 89.99) && (finalgrade >= 79.99))
        {
            grade = 'B';
        }
        else if ((finalgrade <= 79.99) && (finalgrade >= 69.99))
        {
            grade = 'C';
        }   
        else if ((finalgrade <= 69.99) && (finalgrade >= 60.00))
        {
            grade = 'D';
        }

    //output    
        System.out.printf("First Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nIntended Major: %s\nIST Class: %s\nYour final grade is: %s\nfinal letter grade: %s",first_name, last_name, major, ist, final_grade, grade);

    }

}
```

Comment: In addition that doesn't work correctly. It doesn't print out the letter grade.

Comment: Consider adding any additional comments for your own question directly to the question via the "Edit" link underneath it.

Comment: May be a duplicate but not positive. I'm sure some of the answers there could be your solution: [In Java,Using switch statement with a range of value in each case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873590/in-java-using-switch-statement-with-a-range-of-value-in-each-case)

Comment: This may be different because I'm trying to get my program to print out a letter grade (String or Char), by what ever number grade the user puts in the system( double).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright this is homework so I'll keep the code to a minimum.

I think there's a few options here, and it all depends on what you're allowed to use.

1) The easiest option I would think is to "convert" the double to a String, and use a switch statement with the first character of the String. So if it starts with a 9, it's going to be an A, since you aren't calculating A+/A- it seems.

2) You could round down to the nearest tens place, and cast the double to an `int`, and use the switch statement with an `int`. That way you only have 4 numbers to check. The `default` will be your friend here.

Answer (score 0):

As you have learned, a `double` cannot be used in a switch.

#### [The Switch Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

> Unlike if-then and if-then-else statements, the switch statement can
>   have a number of possible execution paths. A switch works with the
>   byte, short, char, and int primitive data types. It also works with
>   enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types), the String class, and a
>   few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character,
>   Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in Numbers and Strings).

One option is to autobox a `double` into a [`Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) and then get its `int` value:

```
Integer i = d.intValue();
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the info; I will try that now.

Answer (score 0):

Round it to the nearest 10s place, turn it to a string, then switch on the string:

```
String gradePercent = Math.round(finalGrade/10).toString();
switch (gradePercent) {
    "6" : grade = "D"; break;
    "7" : grade = "C"; break;
    "8" : grade = "B"; break;
    "9" : "10" : grade = "A"; break;
    default: grade = "F";
}
```