# I Need to use switch statement for range values in java

Tags: java

I need to implement switch statement for range values I can use if else but I think performance of switch will be better.

I have requirement like if value of variable is in range between 1-150 I will process my logic. If value of variable is in range between 150-300 then some other logic and if range is in 300-450 then some different logic and so on.

So how I can use switch in this case because generally I used switch with fixed values.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you tried first. "_I can use if else but I think performance of switch will be better_" Stop worrying about "performance" on such simple examples. Worry about getting the program to run at all first.

Comment: You could perform some arithmetic to convert each case to a particular constant. But you might be better off using `if` statements. `switch` statements are not for ranges.

Comment: Should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873590/in-java-using-switch-statement-with-a-range-of-value-in-each-case

Comment: Do you have evidence that using if/else does not meet your performance criteria? What *are* those performance criteria?

Comment: If you are concerned about performance, consider profiling your application. You'll probably find that the performance issues aren't in your `if` or `switch` statements, but in GUIs or string manipulation.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you use a formula

```
switch (value / 150) {
   case 0: // 0 - 149
          break;
   case 1: // 150 - 299
          break;
   case 2: // 300 - 449
          break;
   default: // otherwise.
}
```

If you use `(value-1)/150` you get 1-150, 151-300, 301-450 etc

EDIT: case 0 will also accept -148 - 0 in switch ((value-1)/150){...} due to the nature of integer division.  To avoid this if/else statements, as well as the conditional operator, can be used.

Comment: very innovative answer

Comment: @AmberBeriwal cheers, if you divide by 50 for example, you could have different sized ranges without too much complexity.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

If you check the [Java Language Specification for `switch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11), you'll see that the expression after `case` must be a `ConstantExpression` or an `EnumConstantName`.
Neither of these can be a range.

A few alternatives have been pointed out in the comments. You could use an `if` statement; it shouldn't make a lot of difference performance-wise, unless you have a really large amount of cases.
Or you could (as per [this answer, linked in the comments by @tomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873590/in-java-using-switch-statement-with-a-range-of-value-in-each-case)) create separate function to distinguish between the different ranges.

If the ranges are regular (e.g. 101-200, 201-300, etc) you could also use a formula. Beware of rounding errors! Test the edge cases of your formula to make sure it is correct.