# How to convert if-statements to switch statements

Tags: java

My code is supposed to convert scores to letter grades, so I used if statements. Just wondering if there's a way to use a switch statement instead of if-statements. I have no idea how to convert it. Also, is one better than the other?

```
   public static void determineGrade(int numArray[], char letterArray[]) {

   int scoreCount = numArray.length;

   for (int i=0; i < scoreCount; i++) {

        if (numArray[i] >= 90 && numArray[i] <=100) {
            letterArray[i] = 'A';
        }           
        if (numArray[i] >= 80 && numArray[i] < 90) {
            letterArray[i] = 'B';

        }
        if (numArray[i] >= 70 && numArray[i] < 80) {
            letterArray[i] = 'C';

        }
        if (numArray[i] >= 60 && numArray[i] < 70) {
            letterArray[i] = 'D';

        }
        if (numArray[i] >= 0 && numArray[i] < 60) {
            letterArray[i] = 'F';
        }
  }
   displayTestScores(numArray, letterArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public char getGrade(int input){
    switch(input/10)
    {
        case 9: return 'A';
        case 8: return 'B';
        case 7: return 'C';
        case 6: return 'D';
        default: return 'F';
    }
}
```

Then

```
for (int i=0; i < scoreCount; i++) {
    letterArray[i] = getGrade(numArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: This is nice and simple. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions are ranges. Java `switch` statements have cases for *values*, not ranges.

Since you have a limited number of cases, you could list each one of them independently. However, this would make your code *much* longer, with 100 cases.

And there's also some math trickery you could do to find the lower number divisible by 10, and switch on that. But the `if` statement is simpler to implement and read.

All that said, your second expression in the `if` statements is unnecessary, if you use an `else` statement, not an independent `if`. And you want to use an `else`, because it would be silly to continue checking all the remaining cases after the first one whose condition is met.

```
    if (numArray[i] >= 90 ) {  // Can you have values > 100?
        letterArray[i] = 'A';
    }           
    else if (numArray[i] >= 80 ) {  // If we're checking this, we know numArray[i] < 90
        letterArray[i] = 'B';
    }
    else if ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch statement in this case but I wouldn't recommend due to the fact you will have way too many cases. You will use at least 100 cases to input because of your if statement conditions.

```
case 100 ://code
    break;
case 50 ://skip a bit
case 0 :
```

There is way too many cases and a waste of time and lines.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking to produce a switch statement that has cases based on ranges.  It's not really what switch statements are meant for.  the if route is more elegant/a better solution for your case imo.

[In Java,Using switch statement with a range of value in each case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873590/in-java-using-switch-statement-with-a-range-of-value-in-each-case)