# Adding sequence to a csv file

Tags: java, csv

I have created a csv file with randomnly generated player names. Now I have to add these players to a team by appending the team ID to their names. Each team consists of 14 players so I have to loop through these names and add a 1 to the first 14 names, followed by a 2 for the next 14 names. This is what I have so far:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
BufferedReader br2 = null;
String line = "";
String cvsSplitBy = ",";
List<String> spelers = new ArrayList<>();

try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("spelers.csv"));
    try {
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            String[] speler = line.split(",");
            spelers.add(speler[1] + "," + speler[2]);
        }

        File file = new File("\\test.csv");
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
        System.setOut(ps);
        for (int i = 1; i < 65; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 14 ; j++) {
                System.out.println(i + "," + spelers.get(?) + "," + spelers.get(?));
            }
        }
```

After that, I have another issue where I have to append "Captain" after the first of every 14 players, "Starter" after the next 10 and "Reserve" after the remaining 3.

Edit: For clarification:

There are 896 players.
There are 64 teams.
Each team has 14 players

```
1,Klaas,Dembele
1,Jonas,Naingollan
1,Wesley,Vertonghen
1,Bart,Lukaku
1,Mattias,Carrasco
1,Giovanni,Vertonghen
1,Bart,Naingollan
1,Wesley,Dembele
1,Olivier,Dembele
1,Bart,Alderweireld
1,Bart,Dembele
1,Giovanni,Carrasco
1,Sander,Naingollan
1,Klaas,Dembele
2,Klaas,Mertens
2,Ward,Vermaelen
2,Dane,Lukaku
2,Giovanni,Carrasco
2,Klaas,Vermaelen
2,Giovanni,Lukaku
2,Jonas,Vertonghen
2,Klaas,Lukaku
2,Wesley,Vertonghen
2,Mattias,Mertens
2,Giovanni,Carrasco
2,Klaas,Naingollan
2,Mattias,Naingollan
3,Sander,Dembele
3,Dane,Lukaku
```

These are the actual names that I generated. The first 14 player in the list are assigned to team 1, the next 14 to team 2, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Team number:**

In case if you want team numbers 1, 2, ..., 64, just keep the `i`, which then already contains team number.

**Player name from names list:**

Use `spelers.get((i - 1) * 14 + j)`

**Player role:**

just create the role based on `j`:

`j == 0    →  "Captain"`
`j <= 10   →  "Starter"`
`otherwise →  "Reserve"`

hopefully this gives an idea and you can easily convert it into Java code. If not, please let me know.

Comment: I'm afraid i'm not really seeing it, I was able to add the correct number with the nested for loop, but then I did not have an index to get the correct values from my list.

Comment: @Audiosleef – regarding team numbers, your question is a bit unclear. Do you want to have team numbers 1, 2, 1, 2, etc.  or 1, 2, 3, ..., 64? It would be the best if you could create a short sample CSV with expected results and insert in into the question.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was being unclear, I modified to post with additional information.

Comment: @Audiosleef – I think my answer should now cover your both questions. If anything is unclear, please ask me.

Comment: Yes, but which number do I use then as an index for the .get() method on the spelers list?

Comment: `(i - 1) * 14 + j`.  And your third CSV column won't be getting value from `spelers` again, but getting a role of the player, if I understand end of your question correctly.

Comment: your answer (i - 1) * 14 + j did the trick, the second spelers.get() was unneccessary. I'll give the roles a shot tomorrow but I think i'll implement a switch statement in the inner for loop that should do the trick. Thank you for your help !

Comment: @Audiosleef – Java does not have [ranges in `switch` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873590/in-java-using-switch-statement-with-a-range-of-value-in-each-case) so maybe roles will be easier using `if` or using `?:` operator.