# Switch Statement: Cases to hold multiple values

Tags: java, switch-statement

How would I create a switch statement where I want a case to be a range of values? For example, I want a case to be between the values of 1-100.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using switch statement with a range of value in each case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873590/using-switch-statement-with-a-range-of-value-in-each-case)

Comment: First question is *why use a switch statement for that?* Unless you can represent your ranges as a single value (such as using an enum), you should use an if block.